# Getting Report with one MySQL query

Tags: mysql, select, report

I have a MySQL Table 'logs' with the below data

```
id  username    status   statusdatetime   mailid
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   abc         pull     3/21/2013 10:04  1753
2   abc         step1    3/21/2013 10:13  1753
3   abc         step2    3/21/2013 10:17  1753
4   abc         step1    3/21/2013 10:46  1753
5   abc         step2    3/21/2013 10:54  1753
6   abc         step3    3/21/2013 11:09  1753
7   abc         mailsent 3/21/2013 11:10  1753
8   abc         pull     3/21/2013 11:11  2113
9   abc         step1    3/21/2013 11:18  2113
10  abc         step1    3/21/2013 11:32  2113
11  abc         step2    3/21/2013 11:33  2113
12  abc         step3    3/21/2013 11:44  2113
13  abc         mailsent 3/21/2013 11:44  2113
14  def         pull     3/21/2013 10:21  120
15  def         step1    3/21/2013 10:22  120
16  def         step2    3/21/2013 10:36  120
17  def         step1    3/21/2013 10:37  120
18  def         step2    3/21/2013 10:38  120
19  def         step3    3/21/2013 10:39  120
20  def         mailsent 3/21/2013 10:39  120
21  def         pull     3/21/2013 10:40  1203
22  def         step1    3/21/2013 10:41  1203
23  def         step2    3/21/2013 10:50  1203
24  def         step3    3/21/2013 10:54  1203
25  def         mailsent 3/21/2013 10:55  1203
```

The help that i request is the below output:

```
id  username    mailid  Time (Seconds)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   abc         1753    3977
2   abc         2113    1991
3   def         120     1101
4   def         1203    888
```

Explanation:

Each user and each mailid are grouped and the time difference between 'mailsent' and 'pull' from the column 'status' to be calculated!

is this possible in one select query?

Comment: What's the `id` column in the result set? If we ignore that, you just need to join the table with itself to select the matching `pull` for a `mailsent` or vice versa.

Comment: Not quite sure, but perhaps something like `select a.id, a.username, a.mailid, (b.statusdatetime - c.statusdatetime) from logs a, logs b, logs c where a.username = b.username and a.username = c.username and b.status = 'mailsent' c.status = 'pull`. The basic idea is to select the same table into three different ones and joining them on the `username` column. Replacing the `usernames` comparison in the `where` clause with joins would be even more elegant.

Comment: I would also add that if you want separate id's for your output table, you need to wrap your query inside a view so you can have a separate autoincrement id column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT  
   a.username,
   a.mailid, 
   TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(b.statusdatetime, a.statusdatetime)) AS DIFF
FROM 
   tbl a 
INNER JOIN
   tbl b 
ON 
   a.mailid = b.mailid AND 
   a.status = 'pull' AND
   b.status = 'mailsent'
GROUP BY 
   username, 
   mailid
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16c90/3)

Comment: What's the `GROUP BY` for?

Comment: He is expecting time difference for each username, mailId, check the OP expected result.

Comment: WOW! Thank you Meherzad. This is why i love StackOverflow. We have genius in this community.

Comment: @Meherzad I know he is, but that's exactly what you get even without the `GROUP BY` clause. `GROUP BY` makes sense when you use aggregate functions.

Answer (score 1):

If u have same sequence which goes from `pull` to `mailsent` status for each mailid, then use below query

```
 select
     username,
     mailid,
     TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,min(statusdatetime),max(statusdatetime)) as `Time`
 from logs
 group by mailid;
```